# Android app on device Installing but not running

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I have an app that I'm trying to run on my Samsung Galaxy Mega and have a friend testing on his Android phone. Right now its just the basics, I'm learning, and it's debugging fine. The app is your basic Hello World app, and should be running.

How I'm trying to run it:
Rather than deal with eclipse and running it through there, I have my phone set in debug mode and I'm using dropbox installed on my phone and just dropping the APK file in there and running it from there. I have my phone set up so I can install Non-play store apps and it'll go "Installing" and then "Sorry I can't install it" for some reason, I just don't know why. Can anyone help me out?

Basically, the program debugs fine, it won't run on a device, and I've given up on the emulators. I'm installing it from Dropbox, and it won't install.

I'm also using Windows 8, if that helps, but it does the same with Linux, same program, etc.

Thanks for helping a total n00b out. Feel free to call me names.

EDIT: I've got the program installed on my phone, which is running Android 4.2.2. I signed the application and changed the target SDK to 17. However, it doesn't show up in Apps, but does show in the Application Manager. However, it won't allow me to open it, nor is there an icon. Help?

Comment: What's your app's minSdkVersion and maxSdkVersion in your manifest.xml file? And which android version is your device running on?

Comment: The minSdkVersion is 8, and the target is 18,but I don't have a max set. I'm using Android 4.2.2 on my phone (Samsung Galaxy Mega)

Comment: Ok, I changed the target to 17, and signed it when I built it to APK, and it installed, but I don't see it in applications anywhere.. hmm. where did it go?

Comment: To clarify, it's in Applications Manager, but gives me no option of opening it, and no icon in the Apps section.

Comment: Hmm, it should be under your installed apps. I'm not familiar with samsung devices, but I trust they have the app drawer? You should find it in there

Comment: It isn't in the installed Apps, however, when I look in Settings, its under Application Manager.. I can install it and uninstall it, that's about it. Hmm!